# Can't receive xml attachment in email

Tags: php, android, xml, email

I have a xml output file, this file is created using PHP Array. I'm sending the xml file as email attachment automatically using PHP too.

Now I have a tablet application, this application receive, read and display the output of the xml file from the email attachment. (Note: I don't have an internal access of the code of this application).

But unfortunately, I didn't receive the xml file in the tablet application (that I created through PHP) that I sent in the email.

How to fix this? Thank you

I have this errors:

```
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: on line 20

Warning: fopen(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/Test/filename.xml) [function.fopen]: on line 21

Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource on line 22

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource on line 23
```

Notice: Undefined variable: message_body in /home7/homecre1/public_html/Test/Mail.php on line 47
Sent

Here's the Mail PHP

```
<?php
/* Email Detials */
$mail_to = "";
$from_mail = "";
$from_name = "Test";
$reply_to = "";
$subject = "Test only";
$message = "";

/* Attachment File 
Attachment location */
$file_name = "filename.xml";
$path = "www.domainname.com/folder/folder/";

// Read the file content
$file = $path.$file_name;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

/* Set the email header 
Generate a boundary */
$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Email header
$header = "From: ".$from_name." \r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

// Multipart wraps the Email Content and Attachment
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$header .= " boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";

$message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

/* Email content
Content-type can be text/plain or text/html */
$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "$message_body\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

/* Attachment
Edit content type for different file extensions */
$message .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n";
$message .= " name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n";
$message .= " filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n".$content."\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."--\r\n";

// Send email
if (mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    echo "Sent";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

PHP Array to xml

```
<?php 

 header('Content-Type: text/xml');

 $xml_Form = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Form></Form>");
 $xml_Form->addAttribute('label', 'Home Visit Form');
 $Fields= $xml_Form->addChild('Field');
 $Fields->addAttribute('name', 'CP_REASON_CODE');
 $Fields->addAttribute('label', 'Reason Code');
 $Fields->addAttribute('value', '');
 $Fields->addAttribute('type', 'EditText');
 $Fields->addAttribute('format', 'string');
 $Fields= $xml_Form->addChild('Field');
 $Fields->addAttribute('name', 'CP_NOTES');
 $Fields->addAttribute('label', 'Notes');
 $Fields->addAttribute('value', '');
 $Fields->addAttribute('type', 'EditText');
 $Fields->addAttribute('format', 'string');
 $Fields= $xml_Form->addChild('Field');
 $Fields->addAttribute('name', 'CP_PICTURE_RECEIPT');
 $Fields->addAttribute('label', 'Receipt picture');
 $Fields->addAttribute('value', '');
 $Fields->addAttribute('type', 'Picture');
 $Fields->addAttribute('format', 'string');

 $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $dom->formatOutput = true;
 $dom->loadXML($xml_Form->asXML());
 //Echo XML - remove this and following line if echo not desired
 echo $dom->saveXML();
 //Save XML to file - remove this and following line if save not desired
 $dom->save('CashPickup.xml');

 ?>
```

Comment: File locations shouldn't be a URL, but the server path. Try `$path = "folder/";` if running script from the root of your server.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I changed now, I receive the xml file in my email, but in tablet application, i didn't receive the xml file

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll test your code.

Comment: Tested fine for me. Got the email and the file. It's your file path. Plus, you did fill in the areas for the FROM and TO at the top of your script `$mail_to = "";
$from_mail = "";`, right?

Comment: I put an email in from and to and i receive the email and the file but in tablet application is not

Comment: What table application is that? I've no way to help if I don't know what your app does or how it was programmed.

Comment: The application is receive, read and display the output of xml file that attach from the email. Please see the updated question

Comment: Place your present script inside your `htdocs` root folder. Then change `$path = "www.domainname.com/folder/folder/";` to 
`$path = "Test/";`

Comment: The script is now inside the htdocs root folder but still i have that error

Comment: I'm sorry but I have trouble finding the solution. However for the undefined variable warning message, you can add `$message_body = "Hello this is a message.";` near the top of your script.

Comment: There is one thing that could be a problem, this line `$header = "From: ".$from_name." \r\n";` - That should be `$header = "From: ".$from_mail." \r\n";` since a `From:` should be an email and not from a person's name. So, mail may be rejected or sent to Spam because of it. Try that to see if it makes a difference. The From and To should also be filled in your script on your tablet.

Comment: See. But how to solve the other warnings?