# Attach uploaded file to the email without PHPmailer

Tags: php, file-upload, contact-form

I've been trying to create a contact form that lets me upload files and send them via email Ive found a large amount of it on w3schools but I am unsure how to attach it to the email at the bottom of the code. I don't want to use PHPmailer or anything like that because the code is nearly there just need a little help finishng it off.

---

PHP

---

```
<?php  
    $to = 'test@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Website Submission';
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $ref = $_POST['ref'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }


    $body = <<<EMAIL

    <html>

    <p><h3>Email from website.</h3></p>

    <p><strong>Company Name:</strong> $company_name</p>
    <p><strong>Ref:</strong> $ref</p>
    <p><strong>Website:</strong> $website</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> $email</p>
    <p><strong>Tel:</strong> $tel</p>
    <p><strong>Message:</strong> $message</p>

    </html>

    EMAIL;

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: test' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <noreply@email.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
    //$headers .= 'Cc: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n";
    //$headers .= 'Bcc: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n";


    if ($_POST['submit']){
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    echo 'Message Successfully Sent.';
    } else {

        die('Error Email Not Sent');
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: With a little googling you will get the solution like this: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php But I suggest to you to use PHPMailer or other library to make your life easier.

Comment: @lolka_bolka *Hm,* I'm not entirely sure, but I think I've tried that one myself before and it didn't work *for me*. I had to find something else. I'd have to re-test it to be 100% sure.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It seems to have eveything I want such as checking the file size and if the file already exists. Most of them Ive found does not and as in new at php its hard to just jump in and wright it from scratch.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I've confirmed it; it doesn't work.

Comment: @jonathan5660 I have a script that I slightly modified from this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/26771099/ some time back. Have a look at it. It worked for me. You will have to do some modifications as well to make it work with your present code, and look under the comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that would be fantastic

Comment: Have a look at that link above, try and make it work with your code. If you're unable, then I'll try and come up with something. I'm just a tad busy for the next few hours.

Comment: PHPMailer is fine but [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) is better. Both of them are easy to use. And your code will look nicer and it will be even smaller than it is now (not even counting the code you intend to write in order to process the attachment).

Comment: @jonathan5660 Ok. I took a few minutes. I posted an answer below, take a look at it. It should theoretically work.

Comment: PHPMailer is fine and [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) is even better. Take a look at the documentation for [creating messages](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html) and [sending messages](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html). The first block of code from these pages explain how to do everything you need (and even more). Bonus points: if you need to change the transport (the way your message leaves PHP and enters into the mailing system) from `mail()` to `sendmail` or `SMTP` all you have to do is to change a single line of code (see the comments on the sending messages sample).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete rewrite, which tested OK.

*Sidenotes:* You may need to change this `Content-Type: application/xml` but I didn't have to when testing with a `.jpg` and `.zip` file.

You also have spaces before your `EMAIL;` which you cannot have, since it's a [**heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). I've removed them. That would have thrown an error.

```
<?php  

    $to = 'email@example.com';
    $subject = 'Website Submission';
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $ref = $_POST['ref'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

    $body = <<<EMAIL

    <html>

    <p><h3>Email from website.</h3></p>

    <p><strong>Company Name:</strong> $company_name</p>
    <p><strong>Ref:</strong> $ref</p>
    <p><strong>Website:</strong> $website</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> $email</p>
    <p><strong>Tel:</strong> $tel</p>
    <p><strong>Message:</strong> $message</p>

    </html>

EMAIL;

/* Attachment File 
Attachment location */
$file_name = $target_file;

$path = $file_name;

// Read the file content

$file = $file_name;
$file_size = filesize($file_name);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

/* Set the email header 
Generate a boundary */
$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Email header
// $header = "From: ".$from_name." \r\n";

$header = 'From: <noreply@email.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
// $header .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

// Multipart wraps the Email Content and Attachment
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$header .= " boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";

$message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

/* Email content
Content-type can be text/plain or text/html */
// $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";

// this header below is the important one if you want HTML message
$message .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "$body\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

/* Attachment
Edit content type for different file extensions */
$message .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n";
$message .= " name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n";
$message .= " filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n".$content."\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."--\r\n";


if ($_POST['submit']){
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
echo 'Message Successfully Sent.';
} else {

    die('Error Email Not Sent');
} 
?>
```

---

*Original answer*

<strike>Taken/borrowed from [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26771099/), I was able to make it work some time ago when I first saw the question:</strike>

```
<?php

/* Email Details */
$mail_to = "email@example.com";
$from_mail = "email_other_1@example.com";
$from_name = "Test";
$reply_to = "email_other_2@example.com";
$subject = "Test only";
// $message = "Here is your file.";

$message = "";

$message_body = "Hello this is a message.";

/* Attachment File 
Attachment location */
$file_name = "attachment.zip";
$path = "files/";

// Read the file content
$file = $path.$file_name;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

/* Set the email header 
Generate a boundary */
$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Email header
// $header = "From: ".$from_name." \r\n";

$header = "From: ".$from_mail." \r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

// Multipart wraps the Email Content and Attachment
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$header .= " boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";

$message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

/* Email content
Content-type can be text/plain or text/html */
$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "$message_body\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

/* Attachment
Edit content type for different file extensions */
$message .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n";
$message .= " name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n";
$message .= " filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n".$content."\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."--\r\n";

// Send email
if (mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    echo "Sent";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

So with your code, try changing this block:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: test' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <noreply@email.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Cc: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Bcc: noreply@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

**with:**

Sidenote: You may need to change this `Content-Type: application/xml` but I didn't have to when testing with a `.zip` file.

```
/* Attachment File 
Attachment location */
$file_name = $target_file;
$path = "uploads/";

// Read the file content
$file = $path.$file_name;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

/* Set the email header 
Generate a boundary */
$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Email header
// $header = "From: ".$from_name." \r\n";

$header = 'From: <noreply@email.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
// $header .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

// Multipart wraps the Email Content and Attachment
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$header .= " boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";

$message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

/* Email content
Content-type can be text/plain or text/html */
$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "$message_body\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";

/* Attachment
Edit content type for different file extensions */
$message .= "Content-Type: application/xml;\r\n";
$message .= " name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n";
$message .= " filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n".$content."\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."--\r\n";
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it out tomorrow when I have more time and let you know.

Comment: @jonathan5660 You're welcome. However, when testing it, found a bug. I will be making an edit soon.

Comment: @jonathan5660 Ok, I've made up a rewrite for you, and it worked well for me.

Comment: I have tested it and it works great uploads images, when I try other files that are not set to be vaild it throws the correct error but sents the file anyways how would I stop this for security reason and I would like to add multiable upload feilds what would i need to change to do this ?

Comment: Place the block for the file attachment inside the success upload block. @jonathan5660 but now I noticed you placed a new question for DB related http://stackoverflow.com/q/27424593/ which contains what looks to be my code.

Comment: okay, yeah I was trying to get the file root to upload to my database when the form is submitted.

Comment: @jonathan5660 Don't use `$_REQUEST['$target_file']` for the DB, but just `$target_file` or `$_FILES['fileToUpload']` that should work.

Comment: Ive sorted the prevus Error but still having a quiery problem "Error To Update Database: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement"

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO detail (company_name,ref,website,email,tel,message,location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                            $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', 
                                $_REQUEST['company_name'],
                                $_REQUEST['ref'],
                                $_REQUEST['website'],
                                $_REQUEST['email'],
                                $_REQUEST['tel'],
                                $_REQUEST['message'],
                                $_FILES['fileToUpload']
                                );

Comment: @jonathan5660 You left out an "s" in `'ssssss'` add another one `'sssssss'`

Comment: its now saying : Array to string conversion in send_config.php on line 44 and just placing the word Array in my DB.

Comment: @jonathan5660 Try replacing `, $_FILES['fileToUpload'] );` with `, '".$target_file."' );`

Comment: I have tried replacing , $_FILES['fileToUpload'] ); with , '".$target_file."' ); I get a error of "Fatal error : Cannot pass parameter 8 by reference in send_config.php on line 9 :" http://www.codeshare.io/6sSmm